# Use WebP images on website

Tags: css, image, webp

I want try to use images in WebP format as background images on my webpages. 
But I'm not sure, how make condition in CSS that if browser not support WebP format so in this case use classic jpg image.
I find this example code, bud it doesn't work

```
.mybackgroundimage {
    background-image: url("image.jpg");
    background-image: image("image.webp" format('webp'), "image.jpg");
}
```

Comment: The above CSS are feature in CSS4 which browser support is unknown. http://www.w3.org/TR/css4-images/#image-fallbacks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You must use [modernizr](http://modernizr.com/) to detect whether browser support webp or not and then apply appropriate style to it

```
.no-webp .mybackgroundimage 
{
background: url('image.jpg') no-repeat;

}

.webp .mybackgroundimage
{
background: url('image.webp') no-repeat;

}
```

Comment: Its 2016! Is this still the only way to do in CSS3?

Comment: If by any change anyone wanna use webp images as background-image css there is a support which I found today.

Here is the code.

    // Input
    .banner{
        background: url(/img/bannerbg.jpg) no-repeat center;
    }
     
    // Output
    .banner{
        background: url(/img/bannerbg.jpg) no-repeat center;
    }
    @supports (-webkit-appearance:none){
        .banner {
            background-image: url(/img/bannerbg.webp);
        }
    }

Comment: @HardenRahul Firefox follows Microsoft Edge: adds `-webkit-` prefixes

Comment: @HardenRahul, that doesn't work in Safari though.